# Working with Diff Image (Deltas) in Picturebox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I create a picture box and on the first request to my server retrieve the full desktop and display it. On every subsequent request, I'm only getting the diff'ed image which is transparent everywhere except where there are changes.

How can I "overlay" these two images together? Or otherwise combine them in my picture box?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < sourceBitmap.Width; x++)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < sourceBitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        var pixelColor = sourceBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

        // copy all non-transparent pixels
        if (pixelColor.A != Byte.MaxValue) 
        {
            destinationBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, pixelColor);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming both sourceBitmap and destinationBitmap are System.Drawing.Bitmap objects. Source bitmap would be the one you're displaying in the picture box, but don't use the one that is returned by pictureBox.Image property, create a copy with Clone() method and then do a swap, or you'll get an exception.

If this method is too slow, you can try using direct memory access to manipulate bitmap data, using LockBits and UnlockBits methods on Bitmap objects.